# How to Initialise leaf/child stores of MobX State Tree

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx-state-tree

My MobX State tree Model is like this

```
const ProductItem = types
    .model({
        name: types.string,
        price: types.number
    })
    .actions(self => ({
        changePrice(newPrice) {
            self.price = newPrice;
        }
    }));

const ProductStore = types
    .model({
        items: types.optional(types.array(ProductItem), [])
    })
    .actions(self => ({
        add(item) {
            self.items.push(item);
        }
    }));

const AppStore = types.model('AppStore', {
    productStore: types.maybeNull(ProductStore)
});
```

`AppStore` is root store.

I want to create `AppStore` and initialize below data for `ProductStore`. I've created below function to initialize and create store :

```
export const initializeStore = (isServer, snapshot = null) => {

    if (isServer) {
        AppStore.create({
              .....
        });
    }   

    return store;
};
```

I'm not sure how `ProductStore` should be initialized inside `AppStore.create()` with this array :

```
items: [
            {
                name: 'Product 1',
                price: 150
            },
            {
                name: 'Product 2',
                price: 170
            }
        ]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The initial data can be given like this

```
AppStore.create({
  productStore: {
    items: [
      {
          name: 'Product 1',
          price: 150
      },
      {
          name: 'Product 2',
          price: 170
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

as `ProductStore` is used under `productStore` key in your `AppStore`.